# Can I skip operations in nested contexts?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Before nested contexts my life was easy declaring some common functions from NSManagedObjects such as:

- awakeFromFetch
- awakeFromInsert
- validateX
- didChangeValueForKey

Through try and fail, call it, life lessons. I learnt to be more careful about those functions when using inheritance with my entities.

Now jumping to the nested context part of Core Data, I am getting used to see the very same NSManagedObject existing in several contexts. I am trying to grasp a key part of this: The above mentioned functions might be called several times from different contexts, but things like validation, value observation, and initialization are only relevant once. Therefore I normally check if the self.managedObjectContext correspond to the main context I work with. If they are the same, I run the whole function, if not, I just call [super] and return.

Is that the way I am supposed to deal with nested contexts?

Doing this has saved me several times. I was surprised seing awakeFromInsert called more than once for the same object, but even if I abort the initialization part of that function in all contexts but the main one, the information is persistet back to the store. I would like some confirmation that I am dealing with this topic the right way.

**UPDATE:**

Trying to make my ideas clear I wrote a post about this topic in my blog. What I wrote there has saved me several times from invalid entity layouts and other errors. However I am not sure if there are approaches better than mine.

http://www.digital-lumberjack.com/blog/2012/11/surviving-core-data/